# Ruby Shoes errors when trying to set-up gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shoes

When I try and invoke gems such as shown below in Shoes I get a error which I cannot find a reference to online.

```
Shoes.setup do
gem "cucumber"  
end
```

I also tried this with Watir.

when I do i get the error "uninitialised constant Encoding::US_ASCII"

I've seen lots of errors in here but never this one.

OSX - Ruby 2.0.0 also installed via rbenv (never had an issue with gems though)

Comment: Hi. Look [here](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/issues/163) please. Seems like you not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: Ah ha must remember to check github more often, thanks. Issue may be known but still have no found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the gem before you are using it and after you have set it up for shoes.

All you need to is:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem "cucumber"  
end
require "cucumber"
```

Not only for "cucumber", this applies for any gem.

A little note further:

Shoes would setup the gem only once (first time you run your shoes app). You would be able to see the list of gems that would be available to shoes at

```
~/.shoes/+gem/gems/
```

There might be many gems in this directory which shoes can access, in your specific app you need to let shoes know which one of them you will be requiring.. And that's what you missed out.

Hope it helps :)